# URL Rewrite removes last parameter without trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying `mod_rewrite` through `.htaccess` in Apache server. My folder structure is as below:

```
 - www/myproject/
   - api/   
     - index.php
     - api-controllers/
   - css/
   - js/
   index.php
   .htaccess
```

My api requests will look like below:

```
 http://localhost/myproject/api/categories
 http://localhost/myproject/api/category/1
```

I put the below rule to redirect all requests that has `api/` in the url to `api/index.php` with the rest of the url returned as it is.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^api/(.*) api/index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, the redirect seems to remove the last part of the url. For eg. `$_SERVER['REQIEST_URI']` value of

`http://localhost/myproject/api/categories` becomes `/myproject/api/index.php`

and

`http://localhost/myproject/api/category/1` becomes `/myproject/api/category/index.php`

If I include a trailing slash in the url, the last parameter is captured.

`http://localhost/myproject/api/categories/` becomes `/myproject/api/categories/index.php`

and

`http://localhost/myproject/api/category/1/` becomes `/myproject/api/category/1/index.php`

As you can see in my folder structure, the folders after the `api/` in the url do not exist. I get the url params with/without slash for all folders that exist (For eg. `localhost/myproject/api` returns `/myproject/api`). This issue is only when they do not exist.

How do I write this correctly to return all the parameters?

Comment: Having been through continual restructuring myself on a similar scheme, I would suggest that it would be simpler all around if you just have **category.php** and **categories.php** files.

Comment: You haven't specified what you want, and it looks like what you want is not the correct syntax.  You are trying to map two urls to one.  In which case it's easier to have two params such as **/myproject/api/index.php?type=category** and **/myproject/api/index.php?type=categories&number=1**.  You also need two rules to cater for them.

Comment: Category is just one instance. I'm trying to generate the queries dynamically so I cannot hard code the types. I'm fine if the params are returned as query params but that did not happen either. Also, any query param passed in the url (like ?type=..) are also ignored by the rule. Defining a file for each type will have lot of redundant code, something that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: My first comment still stands.  The code will be simpler if you have a file for each type.  Any common code should be in one or more include files.  For instance I have separate files for http-headers, logo/menu, footer, common code, database code etc.  Then you use the rewrite to convert the page number to a param.    Each page type needs to have its own title and description fragments (maybe even keywords).  One giant file is a road to disaster.

Comment: I have separate files for common code as well, which I include where necessary. In this case, I have divided my files by REQUEST_METHOD (one file each for GET, POST etc.) and parametrised everything (the code is common within each request method except for parameters) so my file size is lean (like less than 50 lines of code in each).

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked the issue. I had the below include lines before reading the REQUEST_URI which was causing the issue.

```
include_once('../constants.php');  //<===
include_once('../includes/classes/db.class.php');  //<===

$request_uri = filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Though I did not have any code that changed the global variables, there was a redirection condition in one of the files which was causing the issue. Everything worked as expected after I fixed that condition.

Now, the request response (`$request_uri` variable) is as below:

`http://localhost/myproject/api/categories?u=1&k=4` returns `/myproject/api/categories?u=1&k=4` which is what I need.

So, the mod_rewrite was working fine.